# how to make citation abbreviations clickable in LaTex?

Tags: bibtex, citing

I know that citations in articles can be linked to references automatically via package `hyperref`.

However, consider the case where I abbreviate a reference such as "Blah and Blah (2010)" as BB10 for the rest of the article. Is there a way to also link the abbreviation to the specific reference at the end of the article?

I know that it is possible because I've seen journal editors do it. But I don't know how.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help (“**why isn't this code working?**”) must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See [minimal working example (MWE)](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Comment: Do you happen to use (or are you able to use) the `natbib` citation management package? If so, it's straightforward to set up a citation alias. Please advise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use the `natbib` citation management package, and if you employ a bibliography style which is (a) capable of producing authoryear-style citation call-outs and (b) compatible with the `natbib` package, it's straightforward to set up a "citation alias" for a given entry and to create alias-form call-outs via `\citetalias` and `\citepalias`. Furthermore, if the `hyperref` package is in use, these citation call-outs will automatically be made into hyperlinks to the corresponding entries in the formatted bibliography.

[image]

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{mybib.bib}
@misc{bb:10,
  author = "Albert Blah and Zebulon Blah",
  title  = "Thoughts",
  year   = 2010,
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[round,authoryear]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat} % choose a suitable bibliography style
\defcitealias{bb:10}{BB10}

\usepackage[colorlinks,allcolors=blue]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\noindent
\citet{bb:10} (hereafter: \citetalias{bb:10}) argue that \dots
\bibliography{mybib}
\end{document}
```

Comment: that the answer I was looking for. thank you.

Comment: @King - Just out of idle curiosity: Which bibliography style, or styles, do you employ?

Comment: I am preparing an article for the Astrophysical Journal, which recommends using `aasjournal` bib. style.